# Do regex attributes (g, i, m, s) work in xsd patterns?

Tags: regex, xsd

I have an xsd pattern that is restricted to a few words

```
<xsd:pattern value="text|image|video|swf|circle|arrow"/>
```

I would like to allow the xml coder to type in Text, text, or TEXT.

Brute-force works, by using several patterns, one for each way of typing "text".

But trying a regex like /text/i does not work.

```
<xsd:pattern value="/text/i|image|video|swf|circle|arrow"/>
```

Random stabs at this using parenthesis, brackets, slashes and back-slashes don't work yet.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, those flags are not available in XSD patterns. From http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html:

> Compared with other regular expression flavors, the XML schema flavor is quite limited in features. [...]
>   XML schemas do not provide a way to specify matching modes. The dot
>   never matches line breaks, and patterns are always applied case
>   sensitively. If you want to apply `literal` case insensitively, you'll
>   need to rewrite it as `[lL][iI][tT][eE][rR][aA][lL]`.